# The following _TypeError was thrown building ScreenTwo(dirty, state: _ScreenTwoState#346df): Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I've been trying to make a weather app using api but after I fetch data from api it shows this error when i debug or sometimes it keeps loading  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w725A.png)

i thought it would appear something like this though it didn't happen

here is the code https://github.com/C0nik18/Weather-Flutter

Comment: Add your code so we can help you, rather the error is about you have used null check on some null value.

Comment: Hey mate, welcome to stackoverflow. The problem is you are fetching missing data. Check your data that coming from api, see if there is missing data. According to that make you check in code..

Comment: https://github.com/C0nik18/Weather-Flutter  this is the code

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace that you linked the error is caused by an instance of the `WeatherData` class.

The problem is, that all the variables in that class are nullable (`WeatherDataCurrent?` for example), but in your getters you are trying to return a non-nullable type (e.g. `WeatherDataCurrent`) without checking if that value actually exists.

The linter tried to warn you, so you just added a `!` to your variables in your getters to make the warnings go away, rather than making sure, that your variables are not null.

So what happened is, that somewhere in your code you created an instance of your `WeatherData` class without initializing all of the variables. And then, when you try to access the variables of that instance through the getters in the `build` function of the `_ScreenTwoState` widget (`globalController.getData().getCurrentWeather()` in line 58) the getter fails to find a value of `WeatherDataCurrent` type, it only finds null. That's why the error is thrown.

One way to fix this is to change the variables in the `WeatherData` class to non-nullable types (`WeatherDataCurrent`, etc.), and make sure, that all the variables are initialized correctly when you create an instance of the class. You could assign a default value to them in the constructor to achieve this.

Another option is to leave the variables nullable, but in this case every time you try to access them you need to check whether the value exists or is null.

Whichever option you chose, get rid of the getters in your `WeatherData` class, as every variable in that class is final, so the getters have no purpose in their current form.

Comment: Can you please show me as I can't understand how to accomplish this